# Error with react-scripts in npm run build

Tags: reactjs, linux, npm, react-scripts

trying to build project for first time on new app using

```
npm run build
```

and receiving

```
client/node_modules/.bin/react-scripts: line 11: exec: node: not found
```

thus far I have used

```
chmod +x node_modules/.bin/react-scripts
npm install react-scripts --save
chmod -R 777 /root/.nvm/versions/node/v17.4.0/bin/npm
```

Prior to the first chmod, I was receiving a permissions denial error for the react-scrips

```
client/node_modules/.bin/react-scripts: Permission denied
```

Any thoughts on what to try next?

Edit:

Attempted what mmantach below suggested but I now receive the error

```
/usr/bin/env: node: Permission denied
```

Answer (score 0):

try to remove the node_modules and execute `npm install` and check if it work

Comment: removed node_modules, ran `npm install`, received `/usr/bin/env: node: Permission denied` when I ran `npm run build` afterwards